# How to get wso2 api manager 3.2.0 reference guide in pdf file?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

How can I get `wso2 api manager 3.2.0`  reference guide in pdf file?

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 APIM documentation is a large knowledge base and I don't think we have it in a single pdf file. Here you can find the document repo (https://github.com/wso2/docs-apim/tree/3.2.0) and there are some tools available to convert `md` files to `pdf`. I haven't tried any. However even if you find a good tool, you might have to do some extra work to resolve the paths and images.

Answer (score 0):

The official wso2am-3.2.0 documentation cannot be taken/downloaded in pdf format.

https://lms.wso2.com/courses/wso2-api-manager-developer-fundamentals-v3-2 - This has the fundamentals of the concepts and you can download them in pdf format after the enrolment process.